# Powershell: Can't strip out lastlogontimestamp

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to Powershell and I'm trying to pull out a readable date from this PS script. But all I'm getting back from the variables is the full block of text returned from the original query. I know it has to be something pretty simple. I'm teaching myself here, and I've pieced together this script. But this is as far as I can get it. :/

Thanks

```
$ADUserName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the AD username'
Function LastLogon { 
    get-aduser $ADUserName -properties lastlogontimestamp
    $mydatetime = $ADUserName.lastlogontimestamp
    [datetime]::FromFileTime($mydatetime)
    $time = [datetime]::FromFileTime($mydatetime)
    Echo $time
    Echo $mydatetime
}
LastLogon
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `$ADUserName` variable is being passed into the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet, but the cmdlet doesn't modify that; it returns the result. You aren't assigning the result, so it gets passed to the output stream.

All the rest of your variables rely on the assumption that `$ADUserName` contains properties it doesn't.

So you could modify it like this:

```
$ADUserName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the AD username'
Function LastLogon { 
    $ADobject = get-aduser $ADUserName -properties lastlogontimestamp
    $mydatetime = $ADobject.lastlogontimestamp
    [datetime]::FromFileTime($mydatetime)
    $time = [datetime]::FromFileTime($mydatetime)
    Echo $time
    Echo $mydatetime
}
LastLogon
```

However, you don't need to do the steps you're trying to do. `Get-ADUser` is nice enough to return an object with a property (`LastLogonDate`) that contains `LastLogonTimeStamp` translated as a `[DateTime]` for you:

```
$ADobject = get-aduser $ADUserName -Properties LastLogonDate
$ADObject.LastLogonDate
```

Comment: Okay I understand better now. We're sliding the data for lastlogontimestamp into the $ADObject variable. Then converting it using DateTime. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Drake yes, I added the explanation so you could see why what you were doing wasn't working. But I really recommending skipping the steps altogether and just using `LastLogonDate`.

Comment: Yep I know, and I will stick to that value instead. I misunderstood something I read on technet, and thought that the lastlogontimestamp was the actual replicated value and thus more accurate. I didn't realize that LastLogonDate would give me the same (already converted) information. This is my first Powershell script, and I thank you for your help.

Comment: @Drake you probably read it correctly. `LastLogonTimestamp` is the replicated value (though it's actually less accurate because the value won't be updated unless it's sufficiently old; it's just easier than querying all domain controllers), while `LastLogonDate` is a powershell nicety that translates that value to a `[DateTime]` object.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LastLogonDate` instead of `LastLogonTimeStamp`.  The relationship between the properties is explained [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22461.understanding-the-ad-account-attributes-lastlogon-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogondate.aspx).  Bottom line is that `LastLogonDate` is `LastLogonTimeStamp` that's been converted to a Date object.